# Ionic 5 - Remove ion-back-button text on ios global

Tags: css, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

How can I remove this via css or another method? Shadow CSS does not let me do this on an easy way.

I want to remove it for each page (global)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can give a config object to Ionic in your app's main modules (assuming Angular):

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      backButtonText: '' // Set an empty string to have no text next to the back icon
    }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Full documentation : https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/config#global-config

Answer (score 3):

The way to remove "ion-back-button's text" from IOS via attribute is to add inside the `ion-back-button` tag `text="none"`; so you will have `<ion-back-button text=""><ion-back-button>`

Comment: The correct approach in my opinion! Thank you!